# Should pages in Google Webmaster Tools with zero CTR be removed?

Tags: google-search-console, ctr, clicks

[image: Pages with CTR of zero]

For the past 16 months, my site has pages that have not yet been clicked, while other pages of the site have very high clicks (CTR of the whole site is 21%)
Do you think these pages should be deleted?

Comment: Are the pages useful to users that navigate to them from within your site, as opposed to from search?

Comment: no,
These pages do not have many links from within the site

Comment: It isn't surprising that they get no search traffic then. Linking to your own pages is one of the best ways to improve their rankings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that a page gets no search engine referrals does not in and of itself make that page a candidate for deletion. It is normal for pages to get a very poor CTR when they are not in the top few search results. All of the pages in your screenshot have an average position of 7 or worse.

There are a range of things that you can do for pages with poor CTR:

- Change the title and meta description to better appeal to users.
- Target different (ideally more relevant) keywords.
- Work to improve rankings to get into a position with better CTR. (In your case it sounds like the pages could use more links if you want them to rank better.)

Having some pages with poor CTR doesn't necessarily hurt the SEO of your other pages or site as a whole. That is especially true when the pages are ranked further down the page where pages are *expected* to have a poor CTR.

You would only want to remove pages that have other problems as well when you don't have the time or resources to improve them:

- Very little content
- Poor grammar, spelling, or clarity
- Outdated content
- Factual errors
- Spam
- Duplicate or plagiarized content
- Usability issues

If a page looks high quality and you think that users could find it useful, there is no need to delete it because it isn't getting clicks.